# Foreach loop on a generic list in a class which inherits from a abstract class

Tags: c#, generics, recursion

(The title is not very good I supposed... feel free to change; I hope I can express myself better with an example)

I have the following classes:

```
abstract class AbstractObject<T>
{
List<T> Children { get; protected set; }
}

class A : AbstractObject<A>
{
//I have access to a List<A>
}

class B : AbstractObject<B>
{
//I have access to a List<B>
}
```

Then, at some point I have the following method:

```
private TreeNode PupulateRecursively<T>(AbstractObject<T> _us)
    {
        if (_us.Children == null || _us.Children.Count == 0)
        {
            return new TreeNode(string.Format("{0} - {1}", _us.FormattedID, _us.Name)) { Tag = _us };
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Assert(_us.Children.Count > 0);

            TreeNode node = new TreeNode(string.Format("{0} - {1}", _us.FormattedID, _us.Name)) { Tag = _us };
            foreach (var child in _us.Children)
            {
                TreeNode n = PupulateRecursively(child);
                node.Nodes.Add(n);
            }
            return node;
        }
    }
```

But I'm getting a: `The type arguments for method PupulateRecursively<T> (AbstractRallyObject<T>) cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`, because the `child` var inside the foreach is of type T.

How can I fix this? It is a design issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter to `PupulateRecursively<T>` is an `AbstractRallyObject<T>` but you're passing in a `T`:

```
foreach (var child in _us.Children)           // Children is a List<T>
{
    TreeNode n = PupulateRecursively(child);  //child is a T
```

you *could* define `Children` as a `List<AbstractObject<T>>` whichi would *compile* but I don't know enough about your design to know if it's *right*.

Comment: It apparently works. I'm checking other places in the solution where Children list is accessed, but it looks fine so far. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you call your PupulateRecursively method without the generic argument like this :

```
 TreeNode n = PupulateRecursively<T>(child);
```

Comment: This is not the case, see D Stanley answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to define your collection as `List<AbstractObject<T>>`

```
abstract class AbstractObject<T>
{
    List<AbstractObject<T>> Children { get; protected set; }
}
```